# Lookup pipeline: `$match` local field `$in` array when from value is the array and local value is to be found

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections. I want to do an aggregate on Collection A where it matches an ID. From there, I want to lookup from Collection B where the matched ID from Collection A (local field) is in the array of Collection B (foreign field).

So basically:

Collection A:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('<id>')
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('<id>')
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('<id>')
}
```

Collection B:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('<id>'),
    related: ['<id>', '<id>', '<id>', '<id>']
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('<id>'),
    related: ['<id>', '<id>', '<id>', '<id>']
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('<id>'),
    related: ['<id>', '<id>', '<id>', '<id>']
}
```

Query:

```
db.collection_a.aggregate({
    [$match: {_id: ObjectId('<id>')}],
    // other $lookups...
    [
        $lookup: {
            as: 'collection_b',
            from: 'collection_b',
            let: {id: '$_id'},
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {$in: ['$related', '$$id']}
                    }
                }
                // sorts, projections, etc...
            ]
        }
    ]
    // sorts, projections, etc...
});
```

Desired Result:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('<id>'),
        collection_b: [
            {
                _id: ObjectId('<id>'),
                related: ['<id>', '<id>', '<id>', '<id>']
            },
            {
                _id: ObjectId('<id>'),
                related: ['<id>', '<id>', '<id>', '<id>']
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Result:

```
$in requires an array as a second argument, found: objectId
```

---

Now, I know that switching this up and looking up Collection A on Collection B is possible, however, this is not an option in this instance (Collection A should still be queried, even if it is not present in any document in Collection B). Preferable to keep this to one query.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this :

```
db.collection_a.aggregate(
[{ $match: { _id: ObjectId(' ') } },
// other $lookups...
{
    $lookup: {
        as: 'collection_b',
        from: 'collection_b',
        let: { id: { $toString: '$_id' } },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $addFields: {
                    "related": {
                        "$cond": {
                            "if": {
                                "$ne": [{ "$type": "$related" }, "array"]
                            },
                            "then": [],
                            "else": "$related"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: { $in: ['$$id', '$related'] }
                }
            }
            // sorts, projections, etc...
        ]
    }
}
           // sorts, projections, etc...
]);
```

As it says `$in` takes an array as second parameter and a value you're searching for to be first parameter.

Comment: Sure: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing

Comment: Yes: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing

Comment: @CharlerP : Does all your documents have related field & as an array? Let me know if couple of documents has no related field vs related field as a different type, we can make this query work based on that

Comment: Hmm. It would appear not.

Comment: Throws the same "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing" when added where you have the `$addFields`. This fixes the error when `$addFields` is added to the `$lookup` pipeline before the `$match` stage, however all results are returned, not just matches?

Comment: Still returns everything, not just matches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197300/discussion-between-srinivas-y-and-charpun).

Comment: @charpun  : Did it work or do you still have any issues?

Comment: Still returns all documents in the lookup collection.

Comment: @charpun : I still didn't get what you're looking at, this query should be returning what is expected, I've tested & please check chat room !! If you want everything in collection_a irrespective if it's there in collection_b or not then remove the $match stage..

Comment: I'm saying that the the lookup is returning every document in `collection_b` regardless of whether or not it matches in the `$match` stage.

Comment: @charpun : Did you check my solution in chat room ? How different is the dataset and query in that chat from what you're doing, any difference did you see? Though this is something off topic than initial question of having a certain issue, we can certainly look into the issue. Or do you mean you only need the matched id in related array?