# Setting Relationships in MongoDB with ObjectID only

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql, mean-stack, mern

In MongoDB the relationships can be are set by using the _id of the parent in the child object example In the two objects written below the relationship is set between the two by the owner attribute.

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("52ffc33cd85242f436000001"),
   "name": "Tom Hanks",
   "contact": "987654321",
   "dob": "01-01-1991"
}

{
"_id":ObjectId("52ffc33cd85242f436000001"),
 "owner": ObjectId("52ffc33cd85242f436000001"),  
"address": [
      {
         "building": "22 A, Indiana Apt",
         "pincode": 123456,
         "city": "Los Angeles",
         "state": "California"
      },
      {
         "building": "170 A, Acropolis Apt",
         "pincode": 456789,
         "city": "Chicago",
         "state": "Illinois"
      }
   ]
}
```

My concerns is to take a decision between two collection based on _id attribute, if I use the _id attribute in the child collection should be it of type ObjectID (as shown in the example above) or should the child object use the _id vale from the parent as a string type (eg "owner": "52ffc33cd85242f436000001"), 
what should be the best practice with some pons and cons.

Comment: It would be easy to store and retrieve the values if both have same types, That's pretty common and no need to be discussed !! However if you wanted it to be stored in string it can also be retrieved quiet easily by converting string to ObjectId or the other way using $toString to convert ObjectId to string, all in all you need to have that additional step on reads, which can be avoided if you consider of storing it in ObjectId while writes !! An example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295616/lookup-pipeline-match-local-field-in-array-when-from-value-is-the-array-a/57295796#57295796

Comment: Thanks @srinivasy I had the same though, but why i am rethinking about is because the aggregate function I am writing to pull all the address of a respective owner is not able to resolve ObjectIDs in the $lookup function.{
  from: 'address',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'owner',
  as: 'ownerwitaddress'
} projecting the _Id as string has also not worked    "_id": {
        "$toString": "$_id"
      }

Comment: If you're facing any issue, You can put it here, let's see what it is and we can solve it. Can you edit your question with new changes + desired o/p, I can certainly take a look. Also query what you've now !!

Comment: Thanks @srinivasy I solved my aggregate function, Thanks once again.

Comment: nice & not a problem !!